# Shared read-only data in WCF - choosing InstanceContextMode

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service needing to access a read-only repository of information. This repository is expensive to create which means that it needs to be created once and shared between service calls/instances of the service class. Making the class thread safe in general is not a problem as well as making the respository thread safe. I'm considering two options for sharing the respository:

1. Simply set "InstanceContextMode" to "Single" and "ConcurrencyMode" to "Multiple", create the single service object manually and have the single repository injected into it through the constructor.
2. Use "InstanceContextMode" set to "PerCall" (or "PerSession") and implement a custom service instance provider for my service. This instance provider could inject the single instance of the repository into all service class instances (constructor) as a part of the creation process.

What are the reasons for NOT using option 1 here given my situation (provided that I have submitted enough information about it)? To me it seems to be the easiest? I keep reading that "InstanceContextMode" set to "Single" is bad for performance/scalability but I fail to grasp if this is ALWAYS the case or if it depends on the service properties.

As already mentioned I realize it's possible that I haven't provided enough information about my specific case for any of you to be able to answer.

Best regards,
Johan

Answer (score 0):

> A WCF service needing to access a read-only repository of information. This repository is expensive to create which means that it needs to be created once and shared between service calls/instances of the service class

The above scenario is more likely a case where you have to use a caching mechanism rather than a situation where you have to use "InstanceContextMode".

So you should be able to achieve this by using [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx). You can load your readonly objects in to memory cache and share them among concurrent web service calls safely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That sounds like a good alternative and on the same theme as solution #2 (multiple instances). But I'm still still interested if #1 is a bad solution and if it is: why? To me it is important to understand that part.

Comment: In my opinion, #1 is bad because it makes your service single threaded. If you use this pattern in a API, which can be accessed by several systems or devices, your Api will become virtually unusable. According to MSDN, _Single: Each instance context is allowed to have a maximum of one thread processing messages in the instance context at a time. Other threads wishing to use the same instance context must block until the original thread exits the instance context._

Comment: Isn't that a description of "ConcurrencyMode" and the option "Single" for that setting? In #1 I intend to use "ConcurrencyMode" set to "Multiple" and "InstanceContextMode" set to "Single". To me that means that a single object will be used to serve all service calls and that single object will be used concurrently by multiple calls. This, of course, calls for thread synchronization.

Comment: Yes. Missed the "Multiple" part.  If you set concurrency mode to multiple, all concurrent calls will share the same instance. But in that case, your instance will permanently (almost) stay in the memory and it will not be garbage collected until you restart the service. So you will have potential memory issues.

Comment: That is a good point. I'll consider that! Are there any other issues, performance/scalability-wise or other, that you think I should take into account?